# How to access functions in onPrepare while opening the browser each time in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work(protractor 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.0).I need to login with multiple user credentials.So i need to use incognito window.So i have setup in my config file as given below.

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
 chromeOptions: {
    args: ["--incognito"]
 }
},
```

and i have added

```
browser.restart();
```

after each logout code.But when i am open new incognito windows,i am not able to access the code inside of onPrepare function.my onPrepare function is given below.

```
onPrepare: function() {
 browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
 browser.manage().window().maximize();
 global.testdata = require('./support/testdata.js');
}
```

so how can i access the code inside of onPrepare function while opening the browser each time.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the code within `onPrepare()` into a function and export the function in a `.js` file.

```
// onPrepare.js, move the codes in `onPrepare()` at here  
module.exports = function onPrepareConfig() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    global.testdata = require('./support/testdata.js');
}


// protractor conf.js       
onPrepare: function() {
    // you need to import `onPrepare.js` within this function
    // because the variable `browser` we used in `onPrepare.js`
    // are available inside `onPrepare()`

    var onPrepareConfig = require('./onPrepare.js');
    onPrepareConfig();
}


// the code line where you call browser.restart();
browser.restart();
var onPrepareConfig = require('./onPrepare.js');
onPrepareConfig();
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js based on `javascript` language that is a single thread. So, each test which opens a browser runs in separate process and that's why you don't need `incognito` mode. The issue is how to share between multiple tests different users. The simplest way is:

- create a file in a root of project with different users credentials and in the test `beforeAll()` get credentials and remove this line from file. At the end of test returns it back.

OR

- you create a server with simple API for getting different credentials and use it in the test.
  As you can see it is a little bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But i need to use incognito window, because our application will save the username like in Gmail.And i am fetching the user credentials from our DB.I am entering a table of data(having data of multiple users) by looping each row of data to our application.So i have only one step in my feature file and only one function in my stepdefenition file, within this single function, i need to log out and login to as different user.So that i cannot use beforeAll().

Comment: I don't aware with some Cucumber restrictions. But each your test has: login, test, logout. So this is should be in the test! You should somehow just put different credentials (always next row).